# How to vertically separate Material UI Gridded Paper components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

Goal components are not being spaced like I would like them to be. This is currently what they look like.

[image]

So far, I've tried setting the Paper selector display to flex. I've also tried increasing the spacing properties on the different Grid components. Increasing the space just made the padding expand out.

I would like them to be spaced out vertically from one another instead of overlapping. How can I accomplish this responsively? I want it to look like the diagram below where the red boxes are the goal components and the black box represents the web page.

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getGoals } from "../../actions/goal";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import Navbar from "../dashboard/Navbar";
import ThumbUpAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt";
import ThumbDownAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbDownAlt";
import ChatIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Chat";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import DoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Done";
import {
  Typography,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  makeStyles,
  Grid,
  Avatar,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    height: "auto"
  },
  actionButtons: {
    marginTop: "3vh"
  },
  profileHeader: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  avatar: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: theme.spacing(7)
  }
}));

const Goals = ({ getGoals, auth, goal: { goals, user, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getGoals();
  }, [getGoals]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return loading ? (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Spinner />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Navbar />

        <Container>
          <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.profileHeader}>
            Goals
          </Typography>
          {/* parent grid */}
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            {goals.map(singleGoal => (
              <Grid
                className={classes.paper}
                key={singleGoal._id}
                spacing={1}
                container
                item
                direction="row"
                alignItems="center"
                component={Paper}
              >
                <Grid
                  item
                  container
                  direction="column"
                  justify="center"
                  alignItems="center"
                  xs={3}   
                >
                  <Avatar className={classes.avatar} src={singleGoal.avatar} />
                  <Typography variant="caption">
                    {singleGoal.first_name} {singleGoal.last_name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="caption" className={classes.postedOn}>
                    Posted on{" "}
                    <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{singleGoal.date}</Moment>
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container item direction="column" xs={9}>
                  <Typography variant="body1">{singleGoal.text}</Typography>
                  <Grid item className={classes.actionButtons}>
                    <ThumbUpAltIcon />
                    <ThumbDownAltIcon />
                    <ChatIcon />
                    <DoneIcon />
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
    </>
  );
};

Goals.propTypes = {
  getGoals: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  goal: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  goal: state.goal,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGoals })(Goals);
```

Comment: It will be nice if you can provide a minimum workable example here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for using vertically `<Paper />` with styled to spacing do it like :

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    //flexWrap: 'wrap',
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: theme.spacing(46),
      height: theme.spacing(16)
    },

    padding: theme.spacing(5, 5),
    height: "100%",

    //display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  paper: {
    //margin: theme.spacing(10),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(5) // Change this line for more spacing
  }
}));

export default function SimplePaper() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper} />
      <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper} />
      <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer output : [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-bash-bwr6f)

Comment: Turns out I just needed to add the marginBottom to my Paper selector.

```paper: {
    height: "auto", 
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(3)
  }```

Answer (score 1):

I've created an example of responsive layout using the Grid with Paper components (similar to yours). Hope that helped.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Avatar, Grid, Paper, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  paper: {
    minHeight: theme.spacing(10),
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  avatar: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1.5)
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
    description: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1.5)
    }
  }
}));

export default function SimplePaper() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const users = [
    {
      name: "Jason",
      desc: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
      since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
      scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`
    },
    {
      name: "Jonathan",
      desc: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
      since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
      scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`
    },
    {
      name: "Joshua",
      desc: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
      since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
      scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`
    }
  ];

  const renderPaper = ({ name, desc }) => (
    <Grid
      className={classes.paper}
      component={Paper}
      container
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={3} md={2}>
        <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
          <Avatar className={classes.avatar} />
          <Typography variant="subtitle2">{name}</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={9} md={10}>
        <Typography
          variant="body1"
          align="left"
          className={classes.description}
        >
          {desc}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.root} container direction="column" spacing={4}>
      {users.map(user => (
        <Grid item>{renderPaper(user)}</Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-monad-jv6pv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark